# How can I override class call inside of an imported class in python?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Let say I have the following script in `modul1`:

```
class IN(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class C(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        pass

    def func(self):
        cl = IN()
```

Then I want to use `C` class inside another script:

```
from modul1 import C 

class IN(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class C2(C):
    def __init__(self, x):
        C.__init__(self, x)
```

I can override `C` class's func method by creating a method with the same name in `C2` class.

But how can I override any call of `modul1`'s IN class inside of imported `C` class with `IN` class in the caller `modul2`?
I want to change some functionality of original `IN` class. I want `C` class to call in the row

```
cl = IN()
```

my own `IN()` class with the altered functionality.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-a-monkey-patch

Comment: `from modul2 import C` ?

Comment: @LittleQ  sorry, updated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

module1.py:

```
class IN(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "i am the original IN"

class C(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        pass

    def func(self):
        print "going to create IN from C's func"
        cl = IN()
```

module2.py:

```
import module1

class IN(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "I am the new IN"

class C2(module1.C):
    def __init__(self, x):
        super(C2, self).__init__(x)


print "\n===Before monkey patching==="
C2(1).func()
#monkey patching old In with new In
module1.IN = IN
print "\n===After monkey patching==="
C2(1).func()
```

Output while running the script module2.py:

```
===Before monkey patching===
going to create IN from C's func
i am the original IN

===After monkey patching===
going to create IN from C's func
I am the new IN
```

You can see how the module2's In constructor is being called.

Comment: Could you please explain why If I make the following simple change to `module2.py` you no longer override the class?

Change `import module1` to `from module1 import IN,C`

and change the name of `class IN` to `class IN2` then change `module1.IN = IN2` to `IN = IN2`