# Effect of Submodules on Monkeypatching of Classes in Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, monkeypatching

I have three modules:

`in_mod.py`

```
class IN(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("i am the original IN")
```

`module1.py`

```
from in_mod import IN
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        cl = IN()
```

and `module2.py`

```
from module1 import C
class IN2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("I am the new IN")

C()

import in_mod
in_mod.IN = IN2
C()

import module1
module1.IN = IN2
C()
```

I get the desired behaviour of monkey-patching out the `IN` class and replacing it with the `IN2` class when I use `module1.IN = IN2`.

I would like to understand what the underlying difference between `in_mod.IN = IN2` and `module1.IN = IN2` is in this context.

I am [referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30982436) a related post.

Comment: `IN = IN2` *shadows* the imported version within `module2`, but doesn't actually alter `module1` at all. Any functionality inside `module1` still sees the previous version. What are you actually trying to patch, and why (e.g. for testing)?

Comment: In the first example, `C2` inherits from `module1.c`, but in the second, you import `C2` from `module1`, but inherit from `C` -- I'm not sure why. Could you say more about what "the expected behavior" is for you, and why?

Comment: Yes this is for testing. I am trying to mock out IN with IN2. The module I am trying to test imports IN using `from .. import` and I can't change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`from module import IN` creates a local variable that references `module.IN`; `module.IN` and `IN` are two separate references to the same class. `IN = IN2` changes the local reference, but `module.IN` (which is used by `module.C`) continues to reference the same class.

---

UPDATE

In your edit, `module1.IN` is a global variable in the `module1` namespace that initially *refers* to a class in `in_mod`, but is distinct from the global `in_mod.IN` in the `module` namespace. Changing its value doesn't affect `in_mod` at all. There's no way to directly access `in_mod`'s namespace via `module1`, because you don't import the entire module, just one value from the module.

Comment: ok thanks. I think this is the understanding that I needed. The next question is how I can change the reference used by module.C

Comment: That's what you did in your first example: assign directly to `module.IN`.

Comment: Ok, i've refactored the code in the question quite alot to hopefully make it clearer and closer to what I have in my application. I think I have something that works now, but I'm still not sure I fully understand why. Can you take a look? Thanks

Comment: Ok thanks. This makes sense to me know and works for my application. [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765222/monkey-patch-python-class) also provides a good explanation of this.